# Why isn't ORDER BY using the index?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

This is the table I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `age` (`age`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the output of explain:

```
mysql> explain select * from person order by age\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: person
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10367
        Extra: Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What's going on? Why isn't MySQL using the `age` index to do the sorting? I tried doind `analyze table`, but it didn't make any difference.

Just for reference, here's the distribution of data in the table:

```
mysql> select age, count(*) from person group by age;
+-----+----------+
| age | count(*) |
+-----+----------+
|  21 |     1250 |
|  22 |     1216 |
|  23 |     1278 |
|  24 |     1262 |
|  25 |     1263 |
|  26 |     1221 |
|  27 |     1239 |
|  28 |     1270 |
+-----+----------+
8 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

@grisha seems to think that you can't select a field not in the index. That doesn't seem to make any sense, however, it looks like the following works:

```
mysql> explain select age from person order by age \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: person
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: age
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10367
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And also if I add an index that covers all the field it works as well:

```
mysql> alter table person add key `idx1` (`age`, `id`, `name`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select * from person order by age\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: person
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: idx1
      key_len: 35
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10367
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

@eggyal suggested using index hints. This seems to work as well, and is probably the correct answer:

```
mysql> explain select * from person force key for order by (age) order by age\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: person
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: age
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10367
        Extra: 
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried to supply an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html): `select * from person FORCE KEY FOR ORDER BY (age) order by age`?

Comment: @eggyal: The index hint works, but I'm baffled as to why I need it.

Comment: @eggyal is not true, `filesort is badly named. Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. It has nothing to do with files. Filesort should be called sort.` What @grisha said is correct

Comment: op, http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24

Comment: @ajreal: I never said `filesort` was otherwise: only that an index-based sort should be used here.

Comment: @eggyal i mean the forcing index does not help

Comment: @ajreal: And yet the OP says "*@eggyal suggested using index hints. This seems to work as well, and is probably the correct answer*"

Comment: When all of the columns that one selects can be retrieved from an index without having to perform a lookaside into the table itself, MySQL selects that index `FOR JOIN` and one sees `Using index` in the `Extra` column of the `EXPLAIN` output.  Since the index has been selected `FOR JOIN`, it is also preferred `FOR ORDER BY`.  Which explains why @Grisha's answer of `SELECT age...` or adding a complete covering index works as desired.  However, this should be unnecessary: **the real question is why MySQL does not identify a suitable index `FOR ORDER BY` when none has been chosen `FOR JOIN`.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index can help you in sorting, when you select only index column. In your case you select `*`, therefore `mysql` doesn't use index.

***Why usually index can't help in sorting ?***

If we want to sort some table `t` by field `my_field` using index on `my_field`, we will do :

```
for each my_field f in index, do :
    get all records where my_field = f and add to result
return result
```

Assuming not clustered index, the above will execute as many random I/O's as the number of rows in t(might be huge), whereas simple [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithm will read the data by blocks/pages sequentially and will execute much less random I/O's.

So, of course you can say to db : "I want to do sorting using index", but it's really not efficient.

Comment: Never heard of that.  Are you sure?  It's not documented under [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: I've never heard of that either, but it looks like if I add an index that covers all the fields it works. I don't know what to think.

Comment: @eggyal - I didn't find anything opposite to my answer in documentation you post. How exactly index on particular field will help you sort the whole table ?

Comment: @itsadok - Why are you surprised? See the implementation of external sorting - it has nothing to do with indexes..

Comment: @grisha, first of all, it seems strange that the DB would do all the sorting work when it already has a sorted list in the form of an index. Second, if I add an index hint it *does* work, which makes me think that MySQL simply thinks that the table is too small to bother with the index. I'm no expert, so I hope some consensus will be reached here.

Comment: The documentation even gives examples of index-based sort with `SELECT *`.  Using an index-hint as suggested in [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343173/why-isnt-order-by-using-the-index#comment18209106_13343173) is proof enough that this answer is incorrect. @ManseUK

Comment: @itsadok - I've added some explanation, why index isn't useful in sorting. Hope it will help.

Comment: @Grisha: I'm sorry, but your latest update is even less correct than your original answer.  Reading an index, in-order, is not "random I/O".  Performing a full table-scan and sorting the results will however result in considerable "random I/O" (certainly the disk may be *read* sequentially, *but records must then be reordered* which will require considerable random access).  Your summary that index-based sort is "really not efficient" flies in the face of the MySQL documentation on optimising `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @eggyal - I didn't say that "Reading an index, in-order" will cost random I/O. You will pay random I/O per row, when you fetch the record from disk - you have to do it, because you don't have all the fields in index.

Comment: @eggyal - of course you can and must use index when all the select fields are index fields.

Comment: This answer is correct (+1). There is no where clause, so every row will be returned no matter what. MySQL decides is it cheaper to read all rows from the table in physical order and sort them later in memory (or spill to disk if needed), that is what "filesort" means, rather than read rows in index order to get the ORDER BY part done, only to spend much more time doing random file io when reading each row in random order for a full table scan.

Comment: @MarcAlff: `filesort` is going to be O(*n* log *n*), or worse.  You're seriously suggesting that, for 10367 records, this is *cheaper* than an index-based sort?  The very fact that the OP came here wondering why his index wasn't being used suggests that `filesort` was giving poor performance.  The fact that an index hint gives better performance suggests that reading the index and seeking randomly into the table is better than `filesort` after all.  The only question is why one needs to give such a hint: MySQL should be selecting the index of its own accord.

Comment: @eggyal, "The very fact that the OP came here wondering why his index wasn't being used suggests that filesort was giving poor performance." ... not necessarily, that is a valid question by itself. Beside, where do you see benchmark results ? The edits posted show that using FORCE INDEX or a covering index cause the index to be used, not that is it faster.

Comment: @MarcAlff: Okay, that's fair.  I'd be interested to hear from the OP on this.

Comment: @eggyal: I reached this simplistic scenario while trying to understand a more complicated issue. It seems a always regret doing that... I added 1M rows and reached data_length of 145MB, and I still get filesort, though if I add a LIMIT clause it uses the index. I guess ORDER BY without a WHERE or a LIMIT clause is a corner case that is not really worth investigating too much.